# d3.js appending two labels from a dataset on the Y axis

Tags: d3.js

My data for a horizontal bar graph is an array of objects that look like this:
 {value: -10, dataset:"Corvette", year: "1975"}. The "dataset" labels are on the y axis. I would like to append the "year" label to the "dataset" label, so the labels on the y axis would look like this:

Corvette 1975

So far I can add one or the other to the Y axis but not both. Here is the code I have:

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50},
width = 500,
height = 300;

var data = [{value: -10, dataset:"Corvette", year: "1975"},
{value: 40, dataset:"Lumina", year: "1975"},
{value: -10, dataset:"Gran Torino", year: "1971"},
{value: -50, dataset:"Pomtiac GTO", year: "1964"},
{value: 30, dataset:"Mustang", year: "19655"},
{value: -20, dataset:"Camaro", year: "1973"},
{value: -70, dataset:"Firebird", year: "1975"}];

// Add svg to
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width +       margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top +       margin.bottom).append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' +     margin.top + ')');



// set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleBand()
.range([height, 0])
.padding(0.1);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
.range([0, width]);

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.value;
}));
y.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.dataset;
}));

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", function (d) {
    return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive");
})
.attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(Math.min(0, d.value));
})
.attr("y", function (d) {
    return y(d.dataset);
})
.attr("width", function (d) {
    return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0));
})
.attr("height", y.bandwidth());

// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
 let yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
.call(d3.axisRight(y));
yAxisGroup.selectAll('.tick')
.data(data)
.select('text')
.attr('x', function(d,i){return d.value<0?9:-9})
.style('text-anchor', function(d,i){return d.value<0?'start':'end'})
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Kavitha_2817/2e1xLxLc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you (for any reason) want to keep the same domain, get the year using `tickFormat`:

```
.call(d3.axisRight(y)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
        //filter the data array according to 'd', which is 'dataset'
        var filtered = data.filter(function(e) {
            return e.dataset === d;
        })[0];

        //get the year in the 'filtered' object using 'filtered.year'
        return d + " " + filtered.year
    })
);
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 500,
  height = 300;

var data = [{
  value: -10,
  dataset: "Corvette",
  year: "1975"
}, {
  value: 40,
  dataset: "Lumina",
  year: "1975"
}, {
  value: -10,
  dataset: "Gran Torino",
  year: "1971"
}, {
  value: -50,
  dataset: "Pomtiac GTO",
  year: "1964"
}, {
  value: 30,
  dataset: "Mustang",
  year: "19655"
}, {
  value: -20,
  dataset: "Camaro",
  year: "1973"
}, {
  value: -70,
  dataset: "Firebird",
  year: "1975"
}];

// Add svg to
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

// set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width]);

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.value;
}));
y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.dataset;
}));

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive");
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(Math.min(0, d.value));
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.dataset);
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0));
  })
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
let yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
  .call(d3.axisRight(y)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      var filtered = data.filter(function(e) {
        return e.dataset === d;
      })[0];
      return d + " " + filtered.year
    })
  );
yAxisGroup.selectAll('.tick')
  .data(data)
  .select('text')
  .attr('x', function(d, i) {
    return d.value < 0 ? 9 : -9
  })
  .style('text-anchor', function(d, i) {
    return d.value < 0 ? 'start' : 'end'
  })
```

```css
<style> .bar--positive {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar--negative {
  fill: darkorange;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great suggestion as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could map a concatenated string of your d.dataset and d.year to the y scale, and then use the same concatenated string when positioning your rects using that y scale.

The y axis will then use that concatenated string.

**Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/2e1xLxLc/4/

**Relevant code:**

```
//create a reusable function to concatenate the values you want to use
function yValue(d) { return d.dataset + " " + d.year }

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.value;
}));
y.domain(data.map(function(d){ return yValue(d) }));

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive");
    })
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(Math.min(0, d.value));
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(yValue(d));
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0));
    })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth());
```